# How to return a compressed text column by group in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a simple dataset:

[image]

I want to compress the feature text column in ',' by animal, so my output will look like:

[image]

I appreciate any ideas on it. Thank you

Comment: Is this pandas? Or just list? A simple dictionary? Can't help if you don't provide what you're using. Ideally, show us some code.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ... [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thank you. I will improve my question next time. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a groupby:

```py
>>> df.groupby('animal')['Feature'].apply(','.join)
animal
bird    B,C
cat     A,C
Name: Feature, dtype: object
```

Note: for reproducible setup (preferred to an image):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'animal': ['cat', 'cat', 'bird', 'bird'],
    'Feature': list('ACBC'),
})
```